# OpenGL - Texturing a .obj object with multiple textures c++

Tags: c++, opengl

I've been reading around trying to see how I'd apply multiple textures to an object using a .mtl file and I think I've found the solution and makes sense. How I'm trying to go about it is to split the object into different sections, using the same mesh. So the whole object will be the same except I'll be breaking it down into parts so I can loop through the parts and render them using different materials.

The problem I'm facing is how would I determine when a new material is being used. I understand the .obj file format

```
g front
usemtl Frontal_Black
f 300/213/214 299/214/215 301/215/214
f 301/215/214 302/216/216 300/213/214
# 2 triangles in group

g tire_outSide
usemtl Tire
f 315/217/217 303/218/217 304/219/217
f 315/217/217 304/219/217 305/220/217
f 315/217/217 305/220/217 306/221/217
f 315/217/217 306/221/217 307/222/217
f 315/217/217 307/222/217 308/223/217
f 315/217/217 308/223/217 309/224/217
f 315/217/217 309/224/217 310/225/217
```

and when new materials start, but I'm struggling to grasp the logic on how to go about this when parsing the data. I started to try and create something that would recognise when a new material starts but then I stumbled and thought it would not work.

```
while (!inFile.eof()) {
    string line;
    std::getline(inFile, line);

    if (line.substr(0, 2) == "v ") {//vertices
        std::vector<string> elements = Operations::split(Operations::trim(line.substr(3)), *" ");
        if (elements.size() > 1) {
            std::cout << "Loading vertex data: " << line << endl;
            Vertex * v = new Vertex(std::atof(elements.at(0).c_str()), std::atof(elements.at(1).c_str()), std::atof(elements.at(2).c_str()));
            indexedVertices.push_back(v);
        }
    }
    else if (line.substr(0, 2) == "vn") {//normals
        std::vector<string> elements = Operations::split(Operations::trim(line.substr(3)), *" ");
        std::cout << "Loading normal data: " << line << endl;
        if (elements.size() > 1) {
            Vector3 * v = new Vector3(std::atof(elements.at(0).c_str()), std::atof(elements.at(1).c_str()), std::atof(elements.at(2).c_str()));
            normals.push_back(v);
        }
    }
    else if (line.substr(0, 2) == "vt") {//tex coords
        std::cout << "Loading texture data: " << line << endl;
        std::vector<string> elements = Operations::split(Operations::trim(line.substr(3)), *" ");
        if (elements.size() > 1) {
            TextureCoordinate * t = new TextureCoordinate(std::atof(elements.at(0).c_str()), std::atof(elements.at(1).c_str()));
            textureCoords.push_back(t);
        }
    }

    else if (line.substr(0, 3) == "mtl") {
        MaterialParser * parser = new MaterialParser();
        materials = parser->parseMaterial("objects/" + line.substr(7));
        usingMaterial = true;
        delete parser;
    }
    else if (line.substr(0, 3) == "use") {
        currentObject = line.substr(7);//gets current material name
    }
    else if (line.substr(0, 2) == "f ") {//faces / indices
        if (currentObject != "" && usingMaterial) {
            //recognises new material starts, adds to new vector
        }

        std::cout << "Loading face data: " << line << endl;
        std::vector<string> elements = Operations::split(Operations::trim(line.substr(2)), *" ");
        if (elements.size() > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
                std::vector<string> e = Operations::split(Operations::trim(elements.at(i)), *"/");
                if (e.size() > 1) {
                    verticesIndexed.push_back(std::atof(e.at(0).c_str()) - 1);
                    texturesIndexed.push_back(std::atof(e.at(1).c_str()) - 1);
                    normalsIndexed.push_back(std::atof(e.at(2).c_str()) - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So from this, the first line of my file would be:

mtllib Material.mtl

and my code would parse this file fine, storing all the necessary data. Then we come on to lines that contain "use", which means a new texture is being used and this is where the problem is.

Can someone help me out as to how I'd recognise a new texture has started and therefore I need to start adding the faces to a new vector?

Comment: do you have to implement it yourself? there are obj loaders available, e.g. in OpenSceneGraph (see http://svn.openscenegraph.org/osg/OpenSceneGraph/trunk/src/osgPlugins/obj/obj.cpp)

Comment: Yes I have to do it myself, the .obj loader I have already made works fine. I'm just struggling with splitting it into parts so I can texture it with multiple textures because at the moment it's texturing the whole thing and not using the .mtl file provided

Comment: I don't get your question. As far as I recall obj allows only one material per face group, so `g` (or `o`, which is the same) is your marker saying 'subsequent vertices are from this named group'. You can e.g. create group each time when you see `g`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to do. I don't know how I would make the following faces belong to the group though, especially if there's multiple groups in the .obj file. I'm struggling splitting the file up into groups as I'm not quite understanding the logic of creating a new group every time "g" or "usemtl" is found and then allowing the following faces to belong to this new created group.